# Books about multivariate polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, factoring, book-recommendation

I'm looking for a book on multivariate polynomials, preferably a monograph (could also be a chapter inside another book). I'm interested in what can be said about roots, factoring, irreducibility, generators of ideals, polynomials which have an specific vector as root, etc., with comparisons/deviations from the univariate case, more from a ring-theoretic and computational perspective than from an algebraic-geometrical one. If possible, I would like it to be advanced, but starting from the elementary facts.

Comment: There is a big part of mathematics studying multivariable polynomials called Algebraic Geometry. Hartshorne is a great book for introduction It assumes you know basic abstract algebra, along with commutative algebra.

Comment: @Emre: Thanks for the suggestion but, as I said, I'm looking for a ring-theoretic and/or number-theoretical perspective, more than algebraic-geometrical. In particular I'm interested in what happens over the rationals, the finite fields, and general fields, not only over the reals or complex numbers.

Comment: Also, I'd like to avoid schemes and cohomology...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this helps but some of the things about multivariate polynomials you want are in the book [Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms](http://www.springer.com/cn/book/9783319167206#otherversion=9783319374277) , by Cox, Little and O'Shea.

As I said, I don't know if it is of any help because it is written with a view towards algebraic geometry, but in a friendlier way than Hartshorne's book. Hope it helps. Also, since much time has pass, did you find any other book that helped you?

Comment: Indeed, I had found this very same book and thought of writing the answer myself. There is no need now! :)